# Equivalent of Navigator.pushNamed with Navigator 2.0 in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

First: forgive me if it's a dumb question, but I'm trying to figure out step by step how Navigator 2.0 works and how to implement it in my app; this seems to be the only piece left of this puzzle but I weren't able to find an answer anywhere.

I've followed [this Medium article](https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade) on how to implement the new Navigator inside my Flutter app but I don't get how to use it after I've finished.

I mean: I have replaced `MaterialApp` with `MaterialApp.router`, specifying the custom `RouterDelegate` and the custom `RouteInformationParser` I've created, but how can I switch from the '/home' route to the '/profile' one after I pressed a button?

With the old navigator I would have added a `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/profile)` in the `onPressed` function of the button in the home screen, is it still valid or now should I proceed different?

Comment: Rather than horse around learning the low-level stuff, just use go_router from the pub.  Maintained by the Google team, and pretty much what they intended when all the guts of nav 2 got exposed.

Comment: Wow that seems exactly what I was looking for, thank you! 
I bumped into some packages such as GetX and VelocityX but I had read that depending on those type of packages (which try to offer an additional framework over flutter) is not a great practice.
Happy to see that something specifically for declarative navigation designed from the Flutter team exits.
If you want to answer the question proposing it I’ll be happy to mark it as a solution, otherwise I’ll try it out and then answer the question by myself :)

Answer (score 0):

For navigator 1.0:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/profile');
```

For navigator 2.0 (using go_router package):

```
GoRouter.of(context).pushNamed('/profile');
```